# Problems using the mariadb module for python

Tags: python, database, mariadb, database-connection

I am currently needing to create a python script that access my MariaDB database on my local machine.

My file named `Murphy.py` contains

```
# file: Murphy.py

import mariadb
```

In the same directory as my `Murphy.py` I run the command to update my python to python 3

```
$ brew install python3
```

Then to install mariadb module for python i run

```
$ pip3 install mariadb
```

It returns the message

```
Collecting mariadb
  Downloading mariadb-1.0.6.tar.gz (67 kB)
     |████████████████████████████████| 67 kB 6.4 MB/s 
Building wheels for collected packages: mariadb
  Building wheel for mariadb (setup.py) ... done
  Created wheel for mariadb: filename=mariadb-1.0.6-cp39-cp39-macosx_11_0_x86_64.whl size=59180 sha256=17d128175eab51d0edc8387999d5eb7100f80787f95f595561a061c540f364fd
  Stored in directory: /Users/owenmurphy/Library/Caches/pip/wheels/d7/4a/4f/05b62af6cd28564b274014392f29113b6fedfeaaaaab21441a
Successfully built mariadb
Installing collected packages: mariadb
Successfully installed mariadb-1.0.6
```

Then I try and run the file using the command

```
$ python Murphy.py
```

Which returns the error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Murphy.py", line 4, in <module>
    import mariadb
ImportError: No module named mariadb
```

I am not sure what I am doing wrong. Any help is great!

NOTE: I am running macOS Bug Sur Version 11.2.1

Let me know if more info is needed!

Comment: What is the output of `python --version` ?

Comment: @GeorgRichter it is `Python 2.7.16`

Comment: Nvm, I was able to use a different module for accessing MariaDB.

Answer (score 1):

As the number in pip3 indicates, pip3 installs modules for Python 3, while your standard python interpreter is python 2.7 (which is EOL).

Instead of python use python3 to load MariaDB Connector/Python module.